# What’s a word for someone who appreciates the little things?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I’m looking for an adjective that describes a person who appreciates the little things in life: someone who takes life at a little bit slower a pace, who enjoys being outside  instead of forever inside, and so on and so forth.

Comment: [unsophisticated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsophisticated) *marked by a **lack of refinement or complexity** not sophisticated; **simple**; artless; naive*

Comment: Willy Wonkish??

Comment: @Jack: I only highlighted ***simple*** because it was appropriate for the definition of ***unsophisticated***. When directly applied to *people* I think the long-established connotations such as [Simple Simon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Simon_(nursery_rhyme)) would make it inherently pejorative to many people. I think there's quite a difference between saying *"He's simple"* (he's *stupid*) and *"He likes the simple things in life"* (he's "uncomplicated").

Comment: @Jack: Oh, absolutely. Your two examples (and my final one) would generally be seen as *positive* assessments. The truth is I don't *want* to answer trivial questions like this on ELU. If it had been asked on ELL I would be more than happy to spout on about the subtle (but crucial) distinction between the two different usages of ***simple*** as we're discussing here in comments. But as framed here, I really don't think we're looking at a question of interest to [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @FumbleFingers b/c it's too simple for you?! ;-)

Comment: @Jack: Certainly not! On average, I actually find it *more* challenging to answer questions on ELL. Partly because I try to avoid making prior assumptions about the basic linguistic competence of questioners there, and partly because on ELL I feel more obligated to establish/explain *why* certain aspects of the language are the way they are (with particular regard to whether there are any relevant general principles than can be applied elsewhere, and thus speed up the learning process). Here on ELU it's usually just a matter of *"**This** is the answer. End of story"*.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the term  *[aficionado](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aficionado#Noun)* (“A person who likes, knows about, and appreciates a particular interest or activity; a fan or devotee”), for use in a phrase like  “She's an aficionado of life.”  I don't know of an adjectival form.

The verb *[savor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/savor#Verb)* (“to appreciate, enjoy or relish something”) is relevant, eg  “She savors life.”  Again, I don't know of an adjectival form.

The adjective *[appreciative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appreciative)* (“Showing appreciation or gratitude”) may apply, but is somewhat nondescript and general.  *[Optimistic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/optimistic)*, *[positive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/positive#Adjective)*, and  *[upbeat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upbeat#Adjective)* (“Having a positive, lively, or perky tone, attitude, etc.”), are perhaps more relevant; a sentence like  “Sally's an upbeat person” implies Sally is an active person, appreciative of life, has positive attitude, etc.

The adjectives *[epicurean](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epicurean#Adjective)* (“pursuing pleasure, especially in reference to food or comfort”) and  *[hedonistic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hedonistic#Adjective)* (“Devoted to pleasure; epicurean”) may apply but are slightly pejorative.  (Note, *hedonistic* is antonymic to  *[ascetic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ascetic#Adjective)* (“...characterized by rigorous self-denial or self-discipline; austere; abstinent; involving a withholding of physical pleasure”).)

Answer (score 2):

How about "mindful"? The [exact meaning](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mindful) doesn't match exactly but the spirit of the word (relating to [mindfulness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindfulness_%28psychology%29)) matches what you seem to describe.

Answer (score 1):

moderate, reasonable, restrained, controlled, temperate, sober, steady

Answer (score 1):

This might not be quite what you're looking for but you might like flâneur (It's a word that I'm personally very fond of). Specifically it refers to a person who walks through public spaces, watching and appreciating the world going by. You can use it in a broader sense to refer to a person who views life this way (i.e. not necessarily walking around). However it does have a strong suggestion of at least being in the same area as other people, you might be pushing it a bit to use it to describe someone who enjoys being outside in areas without people.

There's more information here, it seems like you'd be using it in the "6 Other uses of the flâneur" sense http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fl%C3%A2neur#Other_uses_of_the_fl.C3.A2neur

Answer (score 1):

You could try **equable:** (of a person) not easily disturbed or angered, or **tranquil:** free from disturbance; calm. Another option would be [transcendentalist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature_%28essay%29), although that may be muddying the waters a bit.

Answer (score 0):

you may like:

> **simple** *adjective* 2a :  free from vanity :  modest b :  free from ostentation or display   3:  of humble origin or
>   modest position

from m-w.com

Answer (score -1):

This could be characterised as a form of asceticism, which would make the adjective form: ascetic.

Abstemious also comes to mind.

Answer (score -1):

Let me make sure I understand you: you’re looking for someone who takes the time to walk thoughtfully in the park or to take in the untrammelled wilderness where he can stop and smell the roses instead of being forever caught up in the maddening hustle-bustle of the frenetic urban pace that has come to completely dominate to the point of dangerous affliction  far too much of modern so-called “society?

If that is the case, perhaps the best term for this is simply ***uncommonly sane***.

Then again, that doesn’t say **why**. Depending on just where you you would care to place your emphasis, other related terms might include various and sundry selections from the following:

> *happy, healthy, uplifting, pleased, pleasant, wise, temperate, steady, irenic, laid-back, easygoing, poised, unflappable, untroubled, peaceful, serene, placid, relaxing, imperturbable, measured, halcyon, bucolic, enchanted, charmed, tranquil, staid, calm, unruffled, peace-loving, untroubled, composed,  discerning, careful, alive, enlightened, joyful, perspicacious, sophic, alert, percipient, sagacious, insightful, childlike, wonder-filled.*